# How to squash old commits coming from integrating another repo into a branch?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase

I am working in merging two repositories into one repository.

I integrated *repo2* into a branch of *repo1*, keeping all the history of *repo2*. After that, I made extra commits to complete the code integration.

The problem is that now I have decided that I do not want to keep the history of *repo2*, as the number of commits is very high. Therefore, I tried to perform an interactive rebase. The problem here is that the history of *repo2* contains commits with dates going back to a year ago.

The commits that have been added in the new branch look like this:

```
680a4b3  Integration          2 days ago
...
985d7ac  Integration          6 days ago    
23d3762  Latest repo2 commit  2020‑04‑20
...
23df1e4  First repo2 commit   2019‑05‑01
```

When I try to perform the interactive rebase going back to the first *repo2* commit:

```
git rebase 23df1e4 ---interactive
```

The list of commits includes commits coming from both *repo1* and *repo2*. Picking them manually would take too much time.

Is there any way to squash (or doing fixup, discarding the messages) all the *repo2* commits automatically, but keeping the "Integration" ones?

Perhaps it is posisble to execute a rebase that only includes commits from the current branch, but I have not found how it can be done.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to squash the beginning of history :

1. run `rebase -i` starting from the parent of "Latest repo2 commit" :

   ```
   git rebase -i 23d3762^
   ```
2. in the actions, set the action of commit `23d3762  Latest repo2 commit` to `edit`, save and close
   git will rewind to `23d3762`, and wait for you to take action
3. squash repo2's history :

   ```
   # use 'reset --soft' to go back to First commit,
   # while keeping the complete delta in the staging area :
   git reset --soft 23df1e4   # <- use id of "First commit" here
   git commit
   ```
4. tell git to complete the interactive rebase

   ```
   git rebase --continue
   ```

Comment: Worked as a charm! I had to solve merge conflicts throughout the rebase process, but it is alright now. Thank you very much!